# Scipy maximize with constraints

Tags: pandas, scipy, minimize, maximize

The purpose is to find the optimized weight of each factor to maximize a specific value. Scipy only provides optimization to minimize a function so I used a negative sign here to find the maximum value. The codes look ok and scipy can terminate successfully in the end but returned no solution. Can anybody help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# the sum of weights should be 1.
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
        'fun' : lambda x: np.array(sum(x)-1)},
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun' : lambda x: np.array([a for a in x])})

# wt should be a list like [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
def optimizewt(wt):
    s = df[list('ABC')]
    r = df['D']

    # rule to calculate the weighted total score of each row
    ts = lambda x: x*wt

    # apply the rule to get weighted total scores
    f = ts(s)
    a = f.sum(axis = 1)

    # sort the list ascending
    a.sort(ascending=True)
    l = len(a)

    # replace the largest and smallest two scores. set others to 0.
    a[0:2] = 1
    a[(l-2):] = -1
    a[2:(l-2)] = 0

    # multiply the two lists. return the average of the calculated list.
    return -np.mean(a*r)

res = minimize(optimizewt, [0.5,0.5,0.], constraints=cons)

print(res.x)
```

Comment: I repeated your example and got a result.
    In [120]: res
    Out[120]: 
     fun: 0.07414209938661212
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 5
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ])

    In [121]: res.x
    Out[121]: array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ])

Comment: @knagaev thanks for you reply. Can you take another look? I have added another constraint that the weight needs to be greater than 0.

Comment: @knagaev the problem is that  the result will change if I change the initial guess.

Comment: Nearly as the previous result. Out[123]: 
     fun: 0.058325697831144094
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 5
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ])